# Is it possible to beat the Monster Fest challenge with four people on insane?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

This is the challenge on Glitterheim, where you have to beat *tons* of monsters below a time-limit.

We just played it, and by wave eight there are so many monsters that *they are still spawning when the timer hits zero*.

So is it possible with four players?  If not, what's the max number of players that it's actually possible to beat with?

Comment: aye, I don't get it either, perhaps killing monsters faster will make them spawn faster?  Other than that, I don't know if its possible to beat it on insane with multiple people at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just simply doesn't appear to be possible to beat this with more than two players.

Until the devs fix this, it can only be beaten with one or two players.